# Angular site not indexing on Google : Page with redirect

Tags: angular, apache, seo, server-side-rendering

I made a huge mistake, I used Angular believing it will be suitable for SEO and Google Indexing but it seems to be the worst...

Of course, I used Server-Side Rendering (SSR) to preload my site before putting it online. The problem is that I'm getting the error "**Page indexing issues: Page with redirect**" on Google Webmaster Tools.

[image]

My site has the following structure: `website.com/category/page`
So with SSR I get a `/category/` folder with a `/page/` subfolder with `index.html` in it.

So the problem is that when I go to `website.com/category/page` it automatically redirects to `website.com/category/page/` because it's a folder so it adds the trailing slash, then Angular redirects it back to `website.com/category/page` without the trailing slash. So that's one redirect for each page that Google doesn't like and doesn't want to index.

How can I avoid this redirection every time?